# How to make delay between two jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

i've used laravel jobs i tried to dispatch two jobs with delay but it doesn't work .

my idea is to dispatch x jobs with delay between them.

wait 10 sec dispatch -> job 1

wait 10 sec dispatch -> job 2

wait 10 sec dispatch -> job 3

and so on ...

```
artisan queue:work --tries=1  --queue=generate-xml
```

```
generateXML::dispatch($this->account)
                    ->onQueue('generate-xml')
                    ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));
```

Comment: You can just dispatch a new job when the current is finished.

Comment: You need to look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236506

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like either want to pause your main process between submitting jobs or you want stagger the delay on the jobs themselves.

If you really need to pause for ten seconds then you can use [sleep(10)](http://php.net/sleep).

If you want to just enforce a ~10 second wait between jobs then you should add 10 seconds delay to the first, 20 to the second, 30 to the third and so on.

Comment: Misread your answer when I posted mine - when re-reading now, I guess you're suggesting the same in your last paragraph...  Just remember some queues impose maximum delays (like Amazon!)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following bit is done in a loop:

```
generateXML::dispatch($this->account)
                ->onQueue('generate-xml')
                ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));
```

right?
If that's the case, the `delay()` method just delays the execution of the job from the time you queued it, so if you are queueing 10 jobs now that you want to have executed every 10 seconds, you need to increment the delay by 10 seconds on each dispatch you call in the loop.

Alternatively, you can also dispatch a new job at the end of your first one, and then queue the next one with a new delay of 10 seconds as well.

Just remember though that some queues (like Amazon's) don't allow for an infinite delay, but impose limits on how long you can keep items on the queue...