# laravel 6 cannot set delay code for job queue

Tags: php, laravel, redis, cron

i need help for correct delay code for run the job.. im using laravel 6 and now i doing scraping youtube number of view.

let say that i have table that fill with youtube link. when i do scraping to youtube. we need to add delay time before we go to other link. if we dont make delay it. youtube will block our access. i want to add delay maybe 30 second for each loop.

so what i already trid in my app/Console/Commands/GetYoutube.php file is this

```
use App\Models\Youtube;
use App\Jobs\GetYoutubeView;
use Carbon\Carbon;
...

public function handle()
    {  

        $youtubes = Youtube::get();
        foreach ($youtubes as $youtube) { 
             GetYoutubeView::dispatch($youtube->link)->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(30));
        }

    }
```

i tried this code. but still can't add delay 30 seconds for each loop

other think that i add delay code `sleep(30);` on jobs file. here is what i've done in my jobs app/Jobs/GetYoutubeLink.php

```
public function handle()
{ 
  sleep(30);
  // Scraping youtube total number of views code
}
```

but this same. it not delay 30 second for each loop. what is the correct delay code for this.

please help. what is correct delay code in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call dispatch the job is dispatched. You are calling the delay after that. You should create the job and delay the job before dispatching.

```
$youtubes = Youtube::get();
$start = Carbon::now();

foreach ($youtubes as $youtube) { 
    $job = new GetYoutubeView($youtube->link);
    $job->delay($start->addSeconds(30));

    dispatch($job);
}
```

**EDIT**

You where calling multiple now dates before, you should only create one date, and keep adding 30 seconds to it.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but still not work. i tried it. but when i looked into date from table youtube. is it now delay for 30 second for each loop.

Comment: It will? but do you wanna do it with 30 seconds between each loop? this will run first job at 12:00:30 next job at 12:00.30 if you run it at 12:00:00. I guess you want it to run at 12:00:30, 12:01:00, 12:01:30 so forth?

Comment: This should work, what is your problem? or include some code

Comment: this won't work as the loop itself executes almost instantly. `->delay()` doesn't pause the loop, it just sets a queue time in the future. You need to multiple your 30sec by the loop index to space the jobs out.

Comment: Thats wrong as you reuse the same date through the loop it would be spaced out

Comment: The doc says: "If you would like to delay the execution of a queued job, you may use the delay method when dispatching a job. For example, let's specify that a job should not be available for processing until 10 minutes after it has been dispatched". If you delay all your jobs by 30sec they will all be exectued 30sec after "now", but not spaced out.

Comment: Now gets called once so that time is 12:30:30 everytime the loop is executed it adds 30 seconds so first job would be executed.

12:31

12:31:30

then 12:32:00

Comment: if you add 30sec 5 times to 12:30:30 they all end up being 12:31:00. Not sure how to explain it another way tbh...How do you get 12:31:30 by adding 30sec to 12:30:30?

Comment: You keep adding to the same carbon object

Comment: and that's when I realise the object is modified at every iteration. I need holidays, sorry about that!

Comment: No problem mate have a nice rest :)